# Export Eclipse project to text file

Tags: android, eclipse

I would like to print out the code of an Android project I made in Eclipse, so I can show it to other people. Therefore I need a text file containing all the code.

Is it somehow possible to export an entire project to a single text file? Or do I have to copy-paste all java and xml files manually?

Comment: I don't think it can be done with eclipse. Once I needed it too to register the copyright of my apps, and I had to do it manually. So, good luck :)

Comment: I have the same requirement now. So can you please update here whether its possible or not and if possible then how. Finally how did you do that

Comment: @android developer: I didn't find an easy way to do it, so I ended up copying the files manually

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the use case where you want all code in one text file, it would be very messy.

However, I am not sure if there is such a feature in Eclipse but if you know Java I am pretty sure it wouldn't take more than 15 minutes to write your own Java program that does this for you. Recursively going through all files and outputting everything to a new file. 20 lines of code or so.

Comment: I'm making the app for a school assignment and I need to include my  entire code in a .doc file in which I explain how I made it. I don't get what you mean by saying that I have to write a java program?

Comment: Depending on the amount of files it might be easier to write a program that concatenates all the text from all the files then to copy-paste manually.

A school that wants source code in a .doc -.- Sounds like a "good" school!:o